# Create new user from phpMyAdmin

Tags: wp-admin, users, user-meta

I'm trying to copy site that I have created in free web hosting server to my windows pc that runs WP on WAMP. I copied all files, but took wp-config.php from sample site I run on my PC and have done few modification with db connection in it.

Copied site somehow runs on my PC, but now I need to get to wp-admin. I don't know why I can't login with username and pass that perfectly works in free hoster.

I decided to create new user from phpMyAdmin page. But how to deal with password generation? System is angry about empty one. If I export user from another site that runs on my PC and import to current table (wp_users) it doesn't work.

How to solve login problem in copyed site?

Comment: Are you using the same salt in `wp-config.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the user in phpmyadmin, enter the password as text in the user_pass field and there is a “Function” column with drop down boxes. On this field just select MD5 in the function column. When you save it phpMyAdmin will automatically md5 hash it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create password in form of MD5, suggested by @passatgt.

Also one point is missed that you not mentioned so I suggest to check your '`siteurl`' and '`home`' fields from db table.

The two fields you need to edit are '`siteurl`' and '`home`'. Replace the URL contained in "option_value" with http://localhost/yourfoldername/.  It's done.

PS:If this stuff helps you please leave me a comment and support :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can deploy [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) on WAMP, just use the [wp user create](http://wp-cli.org/commands/user/create/) command.  A much saner way to do it than trying to do it in phpMyAdmin.